# Pigpio for I2C slave on Pi Zero and the timing of data from the master

Tags: python, i2c, pi-zero-w, pigpio

I'm using the pigpio library through pigpiod running on a Rpi Zero configured as a slave. The master is an ATMega328PB. On the Pi I am testing using a modified version of the python script provided in the documentation: [bsc_i2c](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#bsc_i2c).

The communications are working very well and individual register and byte/word transmission from the master arrives on the slave with no issues. However I noticed that sending a series of messages, which are NOT repeated starts, results in the slave client code receiving all the messages and data together in the single event callback.

For example, on the master side I send 2 messages, first is a byte to a register, the next is a word to a register that holds 2 bytes:

```
twi.SendByte(PI_I2C_ADDRESS, PI_BATTERY_LEVEL_REGISTER, pct);
twi.SendWord(PI_I2C_ADDRESS, PI_FREE_TEXT_REGISTER, bl);
```

On the slave (Pi) side I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import pigpio

# GPIO 19 (SCL)
# GPIO 18 (SDA)

I2C_ADDR=0x01

def i2c(id, tick):
    global pi

    s, b, d = pi.bsc_i2c(I2C_ADDR)
    if b:
#        if b > 2:
        print("Got {} bytes! Status {}".format(b, s))
        j = 0
        while j < b:
            print("{}".format(d[j]))
            j = j + 1
def close(pi, e):

    print("Done!")

    e.cancel()

    pi.bsc_i2c(0) # disable peripherial

    pi.stop()

try:

    pi = pigpio.pi()

    if not pi.connected:
       exit()

    # handle slave activity
    e = pi.event_callback(pigpio.EVENT_BSC, i2c)

    pi.bsc_i2c(I2C_ADDR) # configures the BSC as I2C slave

    x = 0
    while x < 1:
       x = x + 1
       time.sleep(60)
       print(x)

except(KeyboardInterrupt):
    close(pi, e)
else:
    close(pi, e)
```

The output of this python script when the master sends the 2 messages as above is:

```
Got 5 bytes! Status 18
2
214
5
1
253
```

And this is correct, 2 is the address of the battery register, 214 is the value of pct, 5 is the address of the free text register and the value of b1 would have been 0x01FD.

Since the master sent two non repeat start messages I would have expected two separate calls to the event callback, presumably so that the first byte could always be relied on to be the register address followed by that register's data (at least for the protocol I am setting up).

Is there a way to tell the pigpio library to enforce or behave in this manner?

If not, will the library guarantee that the first byte in the callback is always a register address (again for my protocol)? Since I know how much data to expect from these messages I can then reliably parse them off the buffer.

My concern is that the callback can be executed but shifts the data such that it may be possible to receive a register value as the last byte on one call and thus the next call starts with its data.

BTW, I started pigpiod with no (default) arguments. I suspect tuning the sample buffer size and/or the sample rate may dictate the behavior of the event callback but I am not sure they are relevant.

Lastly, would this behavior be expected on the C API as well?

Thanks!